# Find the com port of a specific device on command prompt

Tags: command-line, usb, port, device-manager, com

I know we can find it out from the device Manager under ports. But I want to be able to get this info on command line so I can incorporate it in my python script. I looked at tools like WMI, Devcon. Devcon was able to list the USB devices connected to it but not which COM port the device is assigned to. Anybody knows a way to achieve this?

If it helps, my device I am trying to locate is USB Serial Converter

> DEVCON Findall =USB
>
> USB\VID_0403&PID_6001\AH02JYRN                  : USB Serial Converter

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. You can use devcon.exe and

> devcon.exe FindAll =Ports

will give you the exact details it will show in Device Manager under Ports section-

> ACPI\PNP0501\1                           :Communications Port (COM2)
>
> ACPI\PNP0501\2                           : Communications Port (COM1)
>
> FTDIBUS\VID_0403+PID_6001+AH02JYRNA\0000 : USB Serial Port (COM3)
>
> 3 matching device(s) found.

You can parse this output to find out the COM port number of your desired device.